# Insert using single insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, insert-update

I want to insert the data in my table tblSubscriptions and I only want to use one insert statement.
I am going to insert data for every userId in User Table. The following SQL doesnot work.

```
Insert tblSubscriptions (UserID, ProductID, isACtive, SubscriptionDays, Price, MonthlyPrice, ProductType, CurrencyID)
Values ((Select userID From tblUser where SubscriptionType in(1, 0, null)), 7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 30, 1)
```

How to do this using one insert statement i.e Without cursors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Query

```
INSERT INTO tblSubscriptions (UserID, ProductID, IsActive, SubscriptionDays, Price, MonthlyPrice, ProductType, CurrencyID)
SELECT UserID, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 30, 1 FROM tblUser WHERE ISNULL(SubscriptionType, 0) IN (1, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Insert tblSubscriptions (UserID, ProductID, isACtive, SubscriptionDays, Price, MonthlyPrice, ProductType, CurrencyID)
Select userID, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 30, 1
From tblUser where SubscriptionType in (1, 0) or SubScriptionType is null
```

The IN clause will not work with NULL

Comment: I'd try both this and the accepted answer. I suspect that if there is a data set that is large, this one might perform better.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove 'Values'

```
INSERT(...)
SELECT ...
```